Android - A problem was found with the configuration of task - Reason: An input file was expected to be present but it doesn't exist
I have an android project, and I recently updated to Kotlin 1.9, Java 17, and Gradle 8.2.
I have been able to successfully update and build everything on my machine, but when I try to build the app in bitrise.io, the build fails with this exception:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':apps:produceAppnameReleaseBundleIdeListingFile' (type 'BundleIdeModelProducerTask').
  - In plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check' type 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.BundleIdeModelProducerTask' property 'finalBundleFile' specifies file 
'/bitrise/src/droid/apps/build/outputs/bundle/appnameRelease/apps-appname- 
release.aab' which doesn't exist.

Reason: An input file was expected to be present but it doesn't exist.

Possible solutions:
  1. Make sure the file exists before the task is called.
  2. Make sure that the task which produces the file is declared as an input.

What I have tried:

Clean Project, Clean Cache, Invalidate & Restart
Running ./gradlew app:assembleRelease -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true --dry-run in the terminal to determine which step creates the .aab file

This resulted in each task being skipped


Adding some after evaluate rules in the module level build.gradle file to the section that processes tasks:

    android {
        ...
        applicationVariants.configureEach { variant ->
            ...
            afterEvaluate {
                tasks.matching { it.name == "produce${variant.name.capitalize()}BundleIdeListingFile" }.configureEach { task ->
                    task.dependsOn tasks.named("copy${variant.name.capitalize()}Bundle")
                }
                tasks.named("copy${variant.name.capitalize()}Bundle").configure { task ->
                    task.dependsOn tasks.named("bundle${variant.name.capitalize()}")
                }
                tasks.named("produce${variant.name.capitalize()}BundleIdeListingFile").configure { task ->
                    task.mustRunAfter tasks.named("copy${variant.name.capitalize()}Bundle")
                }
            }
    }

There are hundreds of tasks that are generated during this process, but I can't find a way to determine which (if any) are the tasks that create the .aab
Perhaps it is generated somewhere else, but I have not found a suitable solution that will resolve this.
If you have an idea and need more info, let me know and I will post more code.

Update #1
The filepath indicated shows: /bitrise/src/droid/apps/build/outputs/bundle/appnameRelease/apps-appname-
release.aab
However, that is not the naming scheme of the file.
The file that is generated is named:
appname-6.315-99999-QA.aab
in the pattern: variantProductFlavor}-{version}-{build number}-{variantBuildType}
But I'm not sure how to change that file type.  It appears that this has been addressed in the copyBundleTask, and I also added the line:
    if (output.hasProperty('finalBundleFile')) {
output.finalBundleFile.set(file("${buildDir}/outputs/bundle/${variantName}/${artifactName}.aab"))
    }

This doesn't seem to have changed the value for finalBundleFile

Update #2
After successfully renaming and producing the .aab it seems that the bundle is only an empty file that does not actually do anything.
The file is created and renamed correctly, but the bundle is 0b and does nothing.
Currently trying to figure out why the bundle is suddenly no longer created.
Here is the whole code section:

productFlavors {
        project.file('src').list({ d, f -> !'main'.equals(f) && !'test'.equals(f) && !f.startsWith('.') }).each { flavorName ->
            def projectPath = "${project.projectDir}/src/${flavorName}"
            def packageName = PackageUtil.getPackageNameFromBrandFile(projectPath)
            
            // HERE IS WHERE THE APK SHOULD BE SIGNED
            signingConfigs.each { config ->
                if (config.name.equalsIgnoreCase(flavorName)) {
                    "${flavorName}" {
                        applicationId packageName
                        resValue "string", "PACKAGE_NAME", packageName
                        resValue "string", "SHORT_CODE", flavorName

                        dimension 'appnamePlatform'
                        matchingFallbacks = ['appnamePlatform']

                        // Set the signingConfig in the flavor rather than build type. To override,
                        // set the signingConfig in the buildTypes section
                        signingConfig config
                    }
                }
            }

            task("publish${flavorName.capitalize()}", type: Task, { publishTask ->
                if (makeRelease && !URLReplaced && !makeQA) {
                    if (makeAPK) {
                        publishTask.dependsOn "assemble${flavorName.capitalize()}Release"
                    }
                    if (makeBundle) {
                        publishTask.dependsOn "bundle${flavorName.capitalize()}Release"
                    }
                }
                if (makeQA && makeAPK) {
                    logger.lifecycle("Making QA APK because makeQA and makeAPK are true")
                    publishTask.dependsOn "assemble${flavorName.capitalize()}Qa"
                } else if (URLReplaced) {
                    logger.lifecycle("Making QA APK since base or chat url\'s were overridden")
                    publishTask.dependsOn "assemble${flavorName.capitalize()}Qa"
                }
                publishTask.dependsOn "signingReport"

                group = "publish"

                publishTask.doFirst {
                    project.CURRENT_FLAVOR = flavorName.capitalize()
                    logProjectInfo(project)
                }

                publishTask.finalizedBy(uploadBuildFiles)
            })
        }
    }

applicationVariants.configureEach { variant ->
        def variantMatcher = variant.name =~ /([a-z0-9]+)([A-Z][a-z]+)/
        if (!variantMatcher.matches()) {
            logger.lifecycle('UNKNOWN VARIANT CANNOT CONFIGURE VERSIONED UPLOAD TASK')
            return
        }

        def variantProductFlavor = variantMatcher.group(1)
        def variantBuildType = variantMatcher.group(2)

        if (!variantBuildType.equalsIgnoreCase('Debug')) {
            def projectPath = "${project.projectDir}/src/${variantProductFlavor}"
            def newVersionCode = VersionUtil.getVersionCode(project, variantProductFlavor)
            def newVersionName = VersionUtil.getVersionName(project, variantProductFlavor)

            def suffix = variantBuildType.equalsIgnoreCase("Qa") ? "-QA" : ""
            def artifactName = "${variantProductFlavor}-${newVersionName}-${newVersionCode}${suffix}"

            variant.outputs.configureEach {
                outputFileName = "${artifactName}.apk"
            }

            variant.outputs.each { output ->

                // Assign dynamic build variables only in Qa and Release builds (to speed up build times)
                output.versionCodeOverride = newVersionCode
                output.versionNameOverride = newVersionName

                Task copyBundleTask = project.task("copy${variant.name.capitalize()}Bundle", type: Copy) {
                    group = "modify"
                    duplicatesStrategy = 'include'
                    def path = "${buildDir}/outputs/bundle/${variant.name}/"
                    from path
                    into path
                    include "**.aab"
                    rename { String fileName ->
                        "${artifactName}.aab"
                    }
                    doLast {
                        delete fileTree(path) {
                            include "**.aab"
                            exclude "${artifactName}.aab"
                        }
                    }
                }

                Task renameMappingTask = project.task("rename${variant.name.capitalize()}Mapping", type: Copy) {
                    group = "modify"
                    duplicatesStrategy = 'include'
                    def path = "${buildDir}/outputs/mapping/${variantProductFlavor}/${variantBuildType.toLowerCase()}/"
                    from path
                    into path
                    include "**.txt"
                    rename { String fileName ->
                        "${artifactName}-mapping.txt"
                    }
                    doLast {
                        delete fileTree(path) {
                            include "mapping.txt"
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Run the copy tasks once the assemble/bundle tasks are finished
                variant.assembleProvider.get().finalizedBy renameMappingTask

                project.getTasksByName("bundle${variant.name.capitalize()}", false)
                        .first().finalizedBy([copyBundleTask, renameMappingTask])

                output.processManifestProvider.get().doLast {
                    try {
                        def outputDir = multiApkManifestOutputDirectory.get().asFile
                        File manifestPath = new File(outputDir, "/AndroidManifest.xml")
                        // Stores the contents of the manifest.
                        //def manifestContent = file(manifestPath).getText()
                        def newFileContents = ManifestUtil.generateDeepLinkIntent(
                                new File(projectPath),
                                manifestPath.getText('UTF-8')
                        )
                        manifestPath.write(newFileContents, 'UTF-8')
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        logger.warn("Failed to process manifest for variant", e)
                    }
                }
            }

            tasks.configureEach { task ->
                task.doLast {
                    if (task.name.contains("bundle")) {
                        println "Task ${task.name} produces output: ${task.outputs.files.files}"
                    }
                }
            }

            afterEvaluate {
                tasks.matching { it.name == "produce${variant.name.capitalize()}BundleIdeListingFile" }.configureEach { task ->
                    task.dependsOn tasks.named("copy${variant.name.capitalize()}Bundle")
                    task.mustRunAfter tasks.named("copy${variant.name.capitalize()}Bundle")
                }
                tasks.named("copy${variant.name.capitalize()}Bundle").configure { task ->
                    task.dependsOn tasks.named("bundle${variant.name.capitalize()}")
                }
            }

            logger.lifecycle("Configuring [" +
                    "Project: ${project.name}, " +
                    "Flavor: ${variantProductFlavor}, " +
                    "Type: ${variantBuildType}, " +
                    "Output: $artifactName")
        }
    }


Bitrise Configuration YAML
---
format_version: '6'
default_step_lib_source: https://github.com/bitrise-io/bitrise-steplib.git
project_type: other
workflows:
  deploy-android-2024:
    steps:
    - activate-ssh-key@4:
        run_if: '{{getenv "SSH_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY" | ne ""}}'
        inputs:
        - verbose: 'true'
    - activate-ssh-key@4:
        run_if: '{{getenv "SSH_KEY_FOR_QA_DL_PAGE" | ne ""}}'
        inputs:
        - verbose: 'true'
        - ssh_rsa_private_key: "$SSH_KEY_FOR_QA_DL_PAGE"
        - ssh_key_save_path: "$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa"
        - is_remove_other_identities: 'false'
    - script@1:
        inputs:
        - content: |-
            #!/usr/bin/env bash
            # fail if any commands fails
            set -e
            # debug log
            set -x

            echo "Adding dl.appName.com to Known-Hosts"
            mkdir -p $HOME/.ssh/
            touch $HOME/.ssh/known_hosts
            ssh-keyscan -t rsa dl.appName.com >> $HOME/.ssh/known_hosts
        title: Add dl.appName.com to SSH's Known Hosts
    - authenticate-with-github-oauth@0:
        inputs:
        - access_token: "$GITHUB_PERSONAL_TOKEN"
        - username: "$GITHUB_USER_NAME"
    - git-clone@8:
        inputs:
        - reset_repository: 'Yes'
        - clone_into_dir: "$BITRISE_SOURCE_DIR/droid"
    - install-missing-android-tools: {}
    - script@1:
        title: Set Default Environment Variables
        inputs:
        - content: |-
            #!/usr/bin/env bash
            # fail if any commands fails
            set -e
            # debug log
            set -x

            if [ -z "$CUSTOM_BUILD_NUMBER" ] ; then
              envman add --key CUSTOM_BUILD_NUMBER --value "$DEFAULT_BUILD_NUMBER"
            fi

            if [ -z "$SHORTCODE" ] ; then
              envman add --key SHORTCODE --value "$DEFAULT_SHORTCODE"
            fi

            envman add --key SHORTCODE_CAP --value "${SHORTCODE^}"

            #if [ -z "$VERSION" ] ; then
            #  envman add --key VERSION --value "$DEFAULT_VERSION"
            #fi

            if [ -z "$CHAT_SERVER_OVERRIDE" ] ; then
              envman add --key CHAT_SERVER_OVERRIDE --value "$DEFAULT_CHAT_SERVER_OVERRIDE"
            fi

            if [ -z "$REST_SERVER_OVERRIDE" ] ; then
              envman add --key REST_SERVER_OVERRIDE --value "$DEFAULT_REST_SERVER_OVERRIDE"
            fi

            if [ -z "$API_SERVER_OVERRIDE" ] ; then
              envman add --key API_SERVER_OVERRIDE --value "$DEFAULT_API_SERVER_OVERRIDE"
            fi

            if [ -z "$FEED_SERVER_OVERRIDE" ] ; then
              envman add --key FEED_SERVER_OVERRIDE --value "$DEFAULT_FEED_SERVER_OVERRIDE"
            fi

            if [ -z "$GRAPHQL_SERVER_OVERRIDE" ] ; then
              envman add --key GRAPHQL_SERVER_OVERRIDE --value "$DEFAULT_GRAPHQL_SERVER_OVERRIDE"
            fi
    - fastlane@3:
        inputs:
        - work_dir: "$BITRISE_SOURCE_DIR/droid"
        - lane: android pull_assets shortcode:$SHORTCODE rest_server_override:'$REST_SERVER_OVERRIDE'
    - change-workdir@1:
        inputs:
        - path: "$ANDROID_REPO_PATH"
        title: cd $ANDROID_REPO_PATH
    - gradle-runner@2.0:
        inputs:
        - gradle_task: publish$SHORTCODE_CAP
        - gradle_options: "--stacktrace --scan -PbuildNumber=$CUSTOM_BUILD_NUMBER
            -PbaseUrlReplacement=$REST_SERVER_OVERRIDE -PchatUrlReplacement=$CHAT_SERVER_OVERRIDE
            -PapiUrlReplacement=$API_SERVER_OVERRIDE -PfeedUrlReplacement=$FEED_SERVER_OVERRIDE
            -PmakeAPK=true -PmakeBundle=true -PmakeRelease=true -PmakeQa=$MAKE_QA
            -Penable-performance-plugin"
        - cache_level: all
        - app_file_exclude_filter: |-
            *apps-*.apk
            *apps-*.aab
            *Test*.apk
        - mapping_file_include_filter: "*/*mapping.txt"
        - gradle_file: "$ANDROID_REPO_PATH/build.gradle"
        title: Build App
    - script@1:
        inputs:
        - content: |-
            #!/usr/bin/env bash
            # fail if any commands fails
            set -e
            # debug log
            set -x

            cd $ANDROID_REPO_PATH
            cp apps/src/$SHORTCODE/res/xml/brand.xml $BITRISE_DEPLOY_DIR

            # Delete copied files
            rm -rf build/outputs
            rm -rf apps/build/outputs

            echo "Copied the following APK files:"
            cd $BITRISE_DEPLOY_DIR
            ls -la *.xml
        title: Save brand file
        is_always_run: true
    - deploy-to-bitrise-io@2:
        inputs:
        - generate_universal_apk_if_none: 'false'
        - bundletool_version: 1.15.4
        - is_compress: 'true'
        - debug_mode: 'true'
        - notify_email_list: "$QA_EMAIL"
        title: Save Apps, Logs, Artifacts
    after_run:
    - post-jira-comment
    meta:
      bitrise.io:
        stack: linux-docker-android-22.04
        machine_type_id: standard
  
app:
  envs:
  - DEFAULT_BUILD_NUMBER: "$BITRISE_BUILD_NUMBER"
  - DEFAULT_SHORTCODE: appName
  - opts:
      is_expand: false
    DEFAULT_REST_SERVER_OVERRIDE: ''
  - opts:
      is_expand: false
    DEFAULT_CHAT_SERVER_OVERRIDE: ''
  - GRADLEW_PATH: "$BITRISE_SOURCE_DIR/droid/gradlew"
  - ANDROID_REPO_PATH: "$BITRISE_SOURCE_DIR/droid"
  - DEFAULT_VERSION: ''
    opts:
      is_expand: false
  - opts:
      is_expand: false
    DEFAULT_API_SERVER_OVERRIDE: ''
  - opts:
      is_expand: false
    DEFAULT_FEED_SERVER_OVERRIDE: ''
  - opts:
      is_expand: false
    DEFAULT_GRAPHQL_SERVER_OVERRIDE: ''
meta:
  bitrise.io:
    machine_type: standard
    stack: linux-docker-android-20.04
    machine_type_id: standard
trigger_map:
- pull_request_target_branch: "*"
  enabled: false
  type: pull_request
  workflow: UnitTests


Update #3
There is less than a day on this bounty. I would love to reward someone if I can get an answer!!
The problem seems to be with a property from a gradle task that can't be renamed from its default name.
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':apps:produceAppnameReleaseBundleIdeListingFile' (type 'BundleIdeModelProducerTask').
In plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check' type 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.BundleIdeModelProducerTask' property 'finalBundleFile' specifies file '/Users/me/appname/droid/apps/build/outputs/bundle/appNameRelease/apps-appname-release.aab' which doesn't exist.
The file apps-appname-release.aab is renamed in a previous step.
I have not been able to figure out how to have this step look for the correct file name.


can you please also share your bitrise workflow YAML?

@medavox Updated post with bitrise workflow YAML

I found the answer in another post: Link To Answer - How to change the generated filename for App Bundles with Gradle?
It seemed no matter how I renamed the bundle the ProduceBudleIdeListingFile step (type 'BundleIdeModelProducerTask') would always append an unwanted string to the name of the file.
This was the final task change that resolved the issue:

import com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask

    tasks.named("sign${variant.name.capitalize()}Bundle", FinalizeBundleTask) { task ->
        task.dependsOn tasks.named("copy${variantProductFlavor.capitalize()}${variantBuildType}Bundle")
        def aabPackageName = "${artifactName}.aab"
        def file = finalBundleFile.asFile.get()
        def finalFile = new File(file.parentFile, aabPackageName)
        finalBundleFile.set(finalFile)
    }


This is an quite clunky method to change the output file-name,
which can be done with the base plugin, without messing around:
base {
    archivesName = "appname_" + version_name
}

Which means, that you can ditch this useless part, which doesn't consider AAB anyway:
variant.outputs.configureEach {
    outputFileName = "${artifactName}.apk"
}

And it should build the AAB with ./gradlew app:bundleRelease
or whatever bundle${flavorName.capitalize()}Release may be.
You're also adding finalizedBy renameMappingTask twice. I'd suggest to run an Exec task remotely , to see what is even there, because the AAB file might not be at the expected location. def path = "${buildDir}/outputs/bundle/${variant.name}/" is definitely not correct.
ls -la /bitrise/src/droid/apps/build/outputs/bundle/ ...

The output directory name is always: productFlavor + buildType (combined), which means this path with the useless slash seems to be wrong: ${variantProductFlavor} / ${variantBuildType}.

For our projects we do also want to produce an .apk along with the .aab. Some of our customers are still on .apk so our bitrise process produces both.
Most of the code you mentioned already existed (this is an old legacy project) and did work prior to my changes. I'm not sure why those file paths would have changed.  Thanks for your input. I am working on incorporating your suggestions.

base.archivesName works for APK and AAB and it appends the build-type, product flavor and the suffix. While when setting "${artifactName}.apk" for everything, this doesn't make much sense.

It's odd. I've put a println in each stage of building, but I'm getting the error that the file being looked for is called: "appname-6.315-99999-QA-appname-release.aab' which doesn't exist." Somewhere the piece "QA-appname-release" is being concatenated to the end of the file name.  Trying to figure out why that is.  The bundle is being created correctly and being named correctly after adding the base plugin. Every println looks correct, but the task is still looking for a file with the wrong name.

I did find the log Task signAppnameReleaseBundle produces output: [/Users/username/appname/droid/apps/build/outputs/bundle/appnameRelease/appname-6.315-99999-QA-appname-release.aab], so it's potentially being renamed in the signing process.

Could this be related to different JDK releases on each machine?
The bitrise.yml you supplied does not specify a 'set-java-version' step.
If the gradle task relies on the underlying bundletool JAR to sign the AAB (this is how it's done when signing manually), then the JDK definitely matters.
eg Java version 17 vs 21, and the Oracle release vs OpenJDK etc.
If you don't know which to use, I recommend Temurin LTS 21.

Even if the latest version of Gradle may run on Java 21, for Android the language level is still Java 17. And this quite likely isn't the actual problem; just see my comment above, which might explain, why it fails to produce AAB with the output-filename set to *.apk. This configuration is being passed as input into the bundle task.

Regardless of which version used, it's still a good idea to rule this out by trying it. After all, it works locally but not on Bitrise. Bitrise uses the gradle.properties etc to replicate build conditions as best it can, But the actual JVM is often forgotten to be explicitly specified as a configuration variable, and whatever is available is just used by default.
